# Access variable in jsf datatable footer?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

As **@BaluC** describe this is the way to do edit or pass the selected row

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
                    <h:column><f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>#{item.id}</h:column>
                    <h:column><f:facet name="header">Value</f:facet>#{item.value}</h:column>
                    <h:column><h:commandButton value="edit" action="#{bean.edit(item)}" /></h:column>
                    <h:column><h:commandButton value="delete" action="#{bean.delete(item)}" /></h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

If I am doing like below it's working fine

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="profGroups">
    <h:column> <h:inputText  value="#{profGroups.min}" /> </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
```

But when trying same object `profGroups` inside  `footer` it's saying it's `NULL`

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="profGroups">
   <h:column>  <h:inputText  value="#{profGroups.min}" />  </h:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
    <h:inputText  value="#{profGroups.min}" />
    </f:facet>
</h:dataTable>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is illogical. How should it know which row exactly you mean to show in footer?

Answer (score 0):

`profGroups` is the variable to iterate on list of item during table's build. At the end, when the footer need to be built, it does not exist.